# facebook login & redirect

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

How can I redirect user to a URL after login is successful using Facebook fb:login

Comment: The Facebook API has extensive documentation. Read it!

Comment: The problem is I'm new and there are too many documentations.. got confused where to start!!

Comment: ok then, what do you mean after a successful login? what code example you are using?

Comment: I just have the fb:login button.. when the user clicks on it, I want to redirect the user to another page if the user allows the login.

Comment: the login opens in a popup or the same page? please add your code..

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the basic example on the FB page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), it would be something like this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');

       window.location = "http://your-site.com/howdy/";

       FB.logout(function(response) {
         console.log('Logged out.');
       });
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```